# How to get user credential while moving to welcome screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created simple home screen for login and register,

Here I have taken readymade code from a channel, and now I need to change little bit..

code is simple, so no more details to explain

just I want to pass Usercredential to my welcome screen...
here is my code

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData)
            {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return WelcomePage(usercredential: 
                //how to get usercredential,
                
              );
            }
          else
            {
              return AuthPage();
            }
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my login page's login code

```
Future signin() async {
    UserCredential? usercredential;
    try {
      usercredential=await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: txtemailcontroller.text, password: txtpasswordcontroller.text);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print("Error is =" + e.toString());
    }



  }
```

and register page's register code

```
Future signup() async {
    UserCredential? usercredential;

    try {
      if (txtconfirmpasswordcontroller.text.trim() ==
          txtpasswordcontroller.text.trim()) {
        usercredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: txtemailcontroller.text,
                password: txtpasswordcontroller.text);

      } else {
        print("passwrod does not match");
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('Error while register' + e.toString());
    }

    if (usercredential != null) {
      String userid = usercredential.user!.uid;
      UserModel newuser = UserModel(
          email: txtemailcontroller.text,
          userid: userid,
          fullname:
              txtfirstnamecontroller.text + ' ' + txtlastnamecontroller.text,
          profilepicture: '');

    }
  }
```

so far I know, user credential generated while createuserwithemailandpassword  and signinwithemailandpassword method, but how to get it here....where I need...

Comment: what do you get in snapshot.data?

Comment: User(displayName: , email: logic@logic.com, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-11-12 08:30:57.223Z, lastSignInTime: 2022-11-12 10:08:45.290Z), phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: , email: logic@logic.com, phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: logic@logic.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: DMJ4kbNhveRPxwjD8NwWmAjsP5u1)

Comment: and y tutor is passing Usercredential to welcomescreen.,is only userid not enough?....I am following him so don't want to insert my logic....his first screen is different than  mine..so confuse how to manage...he has used Navigator to move to welcome screen and I have used stream builder...

Comment: is it possible? or I should change my logic to pass only userid to welcome screen,

Comment: actually I didn't get what your problem is?

Comment: right, I am failing to explain where I Am actually stuck...so leave it for some time and I am moving forward with changing my main page as same as tutor's main page

Answer (score 1):

Add this In your Welcome page:

```
User? currentUser=FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Then you can call it any where and get user details like email & id & display name.

for example:

```
currentUser.email
```

or

```
currentUser.uid
```

Comment: yes that's okay but I want to have Usercredential...